# Select subjects and rdf:type in a SPARQL query

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have a SPARQL query shown below to select subjects having specific labels I defined from DBpedia.

```
SELECT ?subject
WHERE {
  ?subject rdfs:label ?label.
  FILTER ( regex (?label,"^json$", "i") )
}
```

It works for me.

And now I am trying to retrieve `rdf:type` of each subject by this query.

```
SELECT ?subject ?type
WHERE {
  ?subject rdfs:label ?label;
  rdf:type ?type.
  FILTER ( regex (?label,"^json$", "i") )
}
```

But I get an empty result from this.

If replacing `?subject` with a specific resource, it works again.

```
SELECT ?type
WHERE {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/JSON> rdf:type ?type.
}
```

Cannot figure out what happens.
How can I get results as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntactically, there's nothing wrong with your query. I think you're seeing a timeout from DbPedia. Try adding a `limit` clause, to see if that gives you some results.

There is more information on DbPedia's fair use policy [on the web site](http://dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess#p13908-7).

Comment: Thanks!!
Adding `limit` or setting longer `timeout` both work.